# Why Facebook Linter is not seeing my og:image

Tags: facebook, laravel

I have this link:

https://my.kendozone.com/tournaments/1a-copa-hiroshi-kamio/register

When I go to [Facebook linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.kendozone.com%2Ftournaments%2F1a-copa-hiroshi-kamio%2Fregister)

```
Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

But when I see the source of my page, I have:

```
    <title> Kendozone - Registro de competidores </title> <meta property="og:title" content="Registro de competidores"/> <meta name=" twitter:title" content="Registro de competidores"/>      <meta name="description" content="Registrate en el torneo 1a Copa Hiroshi Kamio"/> <meta property="og:description" content="Registrate en el torneo 1a Copa Hiroshi Kamio" /> <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" /> <meta name="twitter:description" content="Registrate en el torneo 1a Copa Hiroshi Kamio" />     
    <meta property="og:locale" content="es"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://kendozone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/home.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://kendozone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/home.jpg" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://kendozone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/home.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://my.kendozone.com/tournaments/1a-copa-hiroshi-kamio/register"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Kendozone"/>
```

What's wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get redirected to https://my.kendozone.com/login at that URL. So, I'd imagine, does Facebook. Facebook will see the same OG tags as an anonymous user hitting that URL.

It's possible ([and recommended by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#identify)) that you present the Facebook crawler's user agent a separate page at that URL with the right OG tags. Note that non-Facebook users can spoof this user agent, so this page shouldn't leak secret details of any kind.

Comment: Ooo it s true. It is an authenticated área. Is there anything I can do to bypass this?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro You could serve a different page to the Facebook crawler's user agent, with the OG tags you want.

Comment: do you have a link? It seems to be what I need!

Comment: Link to what? Just check if it is Facebook and return the og-tags

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#identify